How to convert spherical geometry to ellipsoid geometry c++ vertex generation
I have a question on how to generate ellipsoid vertex geometry in c++. I have the following code:
Sphere::Sphere(const LengthT radius, const LengthT a, const LengthT b, const LengthT c, , std::uint16_t sectorCount, std::uint16_t stackCount) :
    m_radius(radius),
    m_sectorCount(sectorCount),
    m_stackCount(stackCount) {
    const double sectorStep{2 * std::numbers::pi / m_sectorCount};
    const double stackStep{std::numbers::pi / m_stackCount};
    constexpr double half_pi{std::numbers::pi / 2};
    double xy, sectorAngle, stackAngle;
    const auto lengthInv{double(1) / m_radius};
    for(std::uint16_t i{0}; i <= stackCount; i++) {
        Vertex vertex;
        stackAngle = (half_pi) - (i * stackStep);
        xy = m_radius * cos(stackAngle);
        vertex.pos.z = m_radius * sin(stackAngle);
        for(std::uint16_t j{0}; j <= sectorCount; j++) {
            sectorAngle = j * sectorStep;
            vertex.pos.x = xy * cos(sectorAngle);
            vertex.pos.y = xy * sin(sectorAngle);
            vertex.normals.x = vertex.pos.x * lengthInv;
            vertex.normals.y = vertex.pos.y * lengthInv;
            vertex.normals.z = vertex.pos.z * lengthInv;
            vertex.texCords.x = double(j) / sectorCount;
            vertex.texCords.y = double(i) / stackCount;
            verticies.push_back(vertex);
        }
    }
}

This generates a list of spherical coordinates but I am wondering how to do it for the equation:
((x^2)/(a^2)+((y^2)/(b^2)+((z^2)/(c^2)=1
where a, b, and c are used to define the ellipse itself.
I am wondering how to incorporate the a, b, and c into the generative equation
Update!
I developed and tested a solution, it is selected as the answer!

Instead of having only one m_radius you will have 3 radii.

For what reason? shouldn't there be an a b and c squared to work with in an actual equation. The radius could stay at 1...

ellipsoid coordinates is not a unique system. You need to specify the linear eccentricity first. Then there are 2 forms of ellipsoidal-hyperbolic systems: in one-sheet hyperboloid systems the polar axis is the short diameter of ellipsiods; while in two-sheet hyperboloid systems, the polar axis is the long diameter (foci line) of the ellipsiods, with the south sheets getting negative values. You need the large radus of ellipsiods and semi major axes of hyperboloids as coordinates. The 3rd coordinate would be rotation angle on the equatorial plane of ellipsiods(same as spherical) in [0, 2π).

According to the comments I think this will do in terms of: ((x^2)/(a^2)+((y^2)/(b^2)+((z^2)/(c^2)=1
Ellipsoid::Ellipsoid(const double a, const double b, const double c, std::uint16_t sectorCount, std::uint16_t stackCount) :
    m_a(a),
    m_b(b),
    m_c(c),
    m_sectorCount(sectorCount),
    m_stackCount(stackCount) {
    const double sectorStep{2 * std::numbers::pi / m_sectorCount};
    const double stackStep{std::numbers::pi / m_stackCount};
    constexpr double half_pi{std::numbers::pi / 2};

    for(std::uint16_t i{0}; i <= stackCount; i++) {
        Vertex vertex;
        double stackAngle{(half_pi) - (i * stackStep)};
        double xy{m_b * cos(stackAngle)};
        vertex.pos.z = m_c * sin(stackAngle);
        for(std::uint16_t j{0}; j <= sectorCount; j++) {
            double sectorAngle{j * sectorStep};
            vertex.pos.x = m_a * xy * cos(sectorAngle);
            vertex.pos.y = m_a * xy * sin(sectorAngle);
            vertex.normals.x = 2 * vertex.pos.x / (m_a * m_a);
            vertex.normals.y = 2 * vertex.pos.y / (m_b * m_b);
            vertex.normals.z = 2 * vertex.pos.z / (m_c * m_c);
            vertex.texCords.x = double(j) / sectorCount;
            vertex.texCords.y = double(i) / stackCount;
            vertices.push_back(vertex);
        }
    }
}

I am in the process of testing it to make sure there are no errors, but I will post an update if I got something wrong...

Any test results yet? Please update your answer when there are. Generally - and not just on SO - it's better to first check and then answer. On SO, there's also a tactical consideration because unanswered questions are more interesting to reputation-seeking community members than those with one or more existing answers.

Yes it works, this is correct

Please [edit] and update. Don't let your answer stand like this. Comments may be removed at any time or they get ignored. Thank you.
